# Better typing hints in python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

How can I be specific when I am using Union of types, let's say I have wrote a function which accepts either `str` or `list` and outputs whatever type was passed in, consider the following example

```
from typing import Union

def concat(x1: Union[str, list], x2: Union[str, list]) -> Union[str, list]:
    return x1 + x2
```

I want the above example to be more specific like `x1`, `x2` and returned value from the function all three must match the same types, but those types must be either `str` or `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def concat(x1: T, x2: T) -> T:
    return x1 + x2
```

Comment: Where’s the union in this example, I only see one type `T`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: The `T` takes any type and says the output is that same type. If you need `T` to be only for a subset of types you could say, eg, `TypeVar("T", int, str)`.

Comment: Thanks @richard it makes sense, I was not aware about TypeVar also takes additional arguments, the above example is clearly mentioned in to the python docs, I should have checked that before!!!

Answer (score 0):

The typing library has a `@overload` annotation that will do what you want. Note that it doesn't work exactly the same as overloading in other languages like java. You cannot create an overload with a different number of argument.

From the documentation:

```py
@overload
def process(response: None) -> None:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: int) -> tuple[int, str]:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: bytes) -> str:
    ...
def process(response):
    <actual implementation>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload

Comment: Thanks @andrew-harelson but it is too verbose given that, each process have the same stuff inside.